# Manipulate point of tangency

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate

I would like to Manipulate[] the point in which the tangent is drawn. It should display the hyperbola, the asymptotes, the tangent the resulting triangle.
The point X should be from (3,8)
Thank you

````
sol = Solve[x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0, Reals]
{x0, y0} = {x, y} /. First@sol /. x -> 5;
contours = 
  ContourPlot[{x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 0, 
    x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 == 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x0, y0}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x^2/16 - y^2/2 <= 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 >= 0, 
    x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 <= 1}, {{x, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}];

regfigure = RegionPlot[reg, PlotPoints -> 80, PlotStyle -> Orange];

Show[contours, regfigure, PlotRange -> All]```
````

Comment: What is `sol`? Please include its definition.

Comment: sol = Solve[x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0, Reals]; Sorry dint copy it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enclose the code by `Module`, set `c` as the parametric and directly use the inequalities to `RegionPlot`,does not use `ImplicitRegion`.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol, x0, y0, contours, regfigure},
  sol = Solve[x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0, Reals];
  {x0, y0} = {x, y} /. First@sol /. x -> c;
  contours = 
   ContourPlot[{x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 0, 
     x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 == 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x0, y0}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  regfigure = 
   RegionPlot[
    And @@ {x^2/16 - y^2/2 <= 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 >= 0, 
      x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 <= 1}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  Show[contours, regfigure]], {c, 4.1, 9}]
```

[image]

- It is recommend to solve `x` from `x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1`.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol, x0, y0, contours, regfigure}, 
  sol = Solve[x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1 && x > 0, x, Reals];
  {x0, y0} = {x, y} /. First@sol /. y -> c;
  contours = 
   ContourPlot[{x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 == 0, 
     x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 == 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x0, y0}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  regfigure = 
   RegionPlot[
    And @@ {x^2/16 - y^2/2 <= 1, x^2/16 - y^2/2 >= 0, 
      x*x0/16 - y*y0/2 <= 1}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  Show[contours, regfigure]], {{c,0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]